# Calculate Variance in PowerBI using dax query

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a variance measure in PowerBI.

This is the data that I have,

```
Month Year MonthNo Value 
Jan    2016  1      700  
Feb    2016  2      800
March  2016  3      900
April  2016  4      750
.
.
Jan    2017 13      690
Feb    2017 14      730
```

And My variance for the Month Number 7 should be like,

```
`{Avg(values(4,5,6) - Value(7)} / Value(7)`
i.e (Average of last 3 months value - current month value) / Current month value
```

How to do this in Power BI? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is okay for you to use a column, I believe you could add one with this code to get what you want:

`Variance = (CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(Sheet1,Sheet1[Value]),FILTER(FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[MonthNo]<=EARLIER(Sheet1[MonthNo])-1),Sheet1[MonthNo]>=EARLIER(Sheet1[MonthNo])-3))-Sheet1[Value])/Sheet1[Value]`

*You'll need to replace all instances of `Sheet1` with the name of your table.*

It'll give you something like this:

[image]

Comment: But when it calculates the average, say for month number 7, it takes the average of (7,6,5) and not average of (6,5,4) which it should. Can you please make that change alone?

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for: `Variance = (CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(Sheet1,Sheet1[Value]),FILTER(FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[MonthNo]<=EARLIER(Sheet1[MonthNo])-1),Sheet1[MonthNo]>=EARLIER(Sheet1[MonthNo])-3))-Sheet1[Value])/Sheet1[Value]`. I added `-1` and changed `-2` to `-3`. I corrected my answer with this too.